# Puzzled about reading from files in Perl

Tags: performance, perl, file, io

When I want to read from a file, I use the following codes:

```
open my $fh, "file_path";
while(<$fh>)
{
    # do something here
}
```

But I'm worry about the IO performance if the file is very large, since it read disk line by line.

In C program, we may prefer to read several bytes (for example: 4096 bytes) into memory at a time ('fread' function called). That can reduce the number of disk IO operations, and benefits performance of the program.

So my question is:　Is there any way to read multiple lines or several bytes from file at a time in Perl ? Or Perl will encapsulate the IO details, and I do not need to worry about that ?

Comment: you can read documentation about `read` function

Comment: premature optimisation? Have you tried using the normal way? Was it too slow?

Comment: Nobody seems to mention `$/ = \4096;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open a file with `open`, then there are various layers between the file handle and the physical resource. These layers can be buffering (can be switched off for output filehandles), or PerlIO-layers.

PerlIO-layers can do encoding or line ending transformation. E.g. to open an UTF-8-encoded file, we would

```
use autodie; # throw fatal exception when open fails
open my $fh, "<:utf8", $filename;
```

Layers can be specified on open with `:layer` after the open mode. The `:uft8`-layer is a shortcut for `:encoding(uft8)`. Layers can also be added via `binmode`.

If you want to read a fixed length string from such a filehandle into a buffer, you can use the very C-ish `read`.

If you want unbuffered access to a file, you can use `sysopen`/`sysread`, but it is very unlikely that you have a situation where this is beneficial. You can't use layers in this case, which sucks for text data.

If you just want to read a whole file at once, you should use the `File::Slurp` module, which is optimized for this usecase. But for regular, line-by-line processing, the readline operator `<$fh>` is good enough.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, by default IO is buffered, see [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and [perliol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perliol.html).

You could use `sysopen` & `sysread` if you want access to the C-style functions.

Comment: I'm sorry for accepting another more detailed answer, but your reply really helps me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

By default, all I/O operations in Perl are buffered. **Buffering maximize the throughput of the I/O operations.** Don't mess with it unless your require special processing because changing the default will **slow down** your program.